# jquery "load" for path contain spaces - Need help !

Tags: jquery, load

I'm working now in a file manager to be used in my simple cms and I have a problem in jquery load function when it takes a path contain spaces . is there any way to overcome this problem ?

```
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
        function get_content(){
            $("#content").load("uploads/flashes/New folder/target.php") ;
        }
    </script>

    <div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can "encodeURIComponent" your url:

```
$("#content").load(encodeURIComponent("uploads/flashes/New folder/target.php"));
```

Javascript encodeURIComponent method is equivalent to URLEncode.

Comment: very good function "escape()" & very good user "Marc Uberstein"

Comment: Thanks! Most people forget about escape() and it's such a handy method for front-end dev.

Comment: **Never** use `escape()`. It is a JavaScript-only non-standard encoding scheme that is not the same as URL-encoding. Use `encodeURIComponent()` in preference, or `encodeURI()` in this case to encode only completely invalid characters like spaces.

Comment: I agree, I never checked if there were other encoders in javascript. Nice one! See: http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

Answer (score 6):

You can use `%20` to represent a space.

```
$("#content").load("uploads/flashes/New%20folder/target.php");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

---

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to do it manually, you could [use `encodeURI()` instead](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp). There are a number of common URI characters that it does not encode, which `escape()` will.

Comment: @web - `escape()` will work for your example, but if you're going to use a method call to accomplish it, you might as well use `encodeURI()`, as that is what it is meant to do.

Answer (score 4):

From the above answers, encodeURI() has worked fine with me. On the other hand, encodeURIComponent() has changed also the representation for the '/' character, with the result of not doing properly the HTTP request to the desired URL. So, I recommend to use the encodeURI() solution in the case that the path String includes '/'.