# How to put &amp; in in URL with jQuery.load?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, load, ampersand

I have a Wordpress page that should load some code from the server using jQuerys load method:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>
jQuery("#mydiv").load("http://localhost/testserver/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/scripts/view/test.php?x=1&amp;y=2&amp;z=3");
</script>
```

My test.php script is:

```
<?php error_log(var_export($_GET,true)); ?>
```

But I am unable to get the parameters x, y, z correctly in the test.php script: The output in the error log shows:

```
'x' => '1',
'amp;y' => '2',
'amp;z' => '3',
```

(If I use x=1&y=2&z=3  in the url string, I just get 'x' => '1', in the error log).

Am I doing something wrong or could this be a Wordpress or jQuery bug?

Comment: Why you using &amp;? Just use &.

Comment: it's &amp not amp 'amp;y' => '2',

Comment: Like I said, when I just use & , i only get 'x' => '1', in the error log.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Example: pass arrays of data to the server.

```
$( "#objectID" ).load( "test.php", { "choices[]": [ "Jon", "Susan" ] } );
```

Comment: Thanks! The data will end up in the $_POST variable, which is preferrable. So in my example the data would be sent as: 
    {x:"1",y:"2",z:"3"}
and output as:
    error_log(var_export($_POST,true));

Answer (score 0):

Use *encodeURIComponent();*

Example

```
var url = "http://localhost/testserver/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/scripts/view/test.php?x=1&y=2&z=3"
url = encodeURIComponent(url);

jQuery("#mydiv").load(url);
```

Alternatively use *.get()*

```
jQuery.get('http://localhost/testserver/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/scripts/view/test.php', {x: 1, y:2, z:3}, function(r){
   jQuery("#mydiv").html(r);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Accepted, as this answers my question more acurately, however I think I prefer Zeto's method.

Comment: Actally, I was too quick accepting this answer. I could not get it to work within Wordpress, although it probably works in other settings (the same answer is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741672/jquery-load-for-path-contain-spaces-need-help )

So I must accept Zeto's answer. Thanks anyhow.