# Simple jQuery .load not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load a txt file into a div and for some reason this simple jQuery isn't working and I can't seem to put my eye on what I am doing wrong.  Any thoughts?  The txt file just contains text that should get loaded into the content div.  I really don't think I am doing anything wrong and I had it working at one point but now it has just stopped

```
<article>
<h1>1 - Location Tachometer</h1>
<script>$("#content0").load("Dashboard/1 - Location Tachometer.txt");</script>
<div id="content0"></div>
<h2>View More</h2>
</article>
```

My jQuery reference is correct but for some reason this isn't working.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you made sure your path to the txt file is correct?

Comment: Yes as in the h1 tags, is reads the file names and cuts off the extension (This is a server side aspx script I wrote).  So if the file name shows up in the h1 tags, then it finds the file and should load it corectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect is could be because of the spaces in your url path. A solution was provided to this problem here: [jquery "load" for path contain spaces - Need help !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741672/jquery-load-for-path-contain-spaces-need-help)

Comment: This was it.  But it also took me some rewriting of server code.  I could always manually get the right pages to load, but to do it dynamically it was always being a pain so I ended up carefully rewriting it out to copy what I had working.  Thank you very much